# Parsing JSON object into BigQuery table

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a multiple visitor profiles in JSON format that look like this -

```
{
"properties": {
        "visitor_id": "011238234d13456005675fghce678fdh3f00cb00d00b40__",
    },   
 "audiences_joined_at": {
        "ti_main_522": 1685423385711,
        "ti_main_224": 1685424724368,
        "ti_main_314": 1685017676965,
        "ti_main_523": 1685424724369,
        "ti_main_129": 1685017676965,
        "ti_main_239": 1685017676965,
        "ti_main_437": 1685424724369,
        "ti_main_506": 1685424724369,
        "ti_main_393": 1685424724369,
        "ti_main_164": 1685017676965,
        "ti_main_197": 1685158341719,
        "ti_main_296": 1685158341719,
        "ti_main_340": 1685158341719,
        "ti_main_263": 1685017676965,
        "ti_main_174": 1685424831154,
        "ti_main_399": 1685424724369,
        "ti_main_354": 1685017676965,
        "ti_main_457": 1685426669254
    }
}
```

I need to turn this into a bigquery table with effectively 3 columns

- Audience: the name of the audience (egs - ti_main_522)
- Date: turning the epoch timestamp into a date
- Count: count of visitorIDs for each date for each audience

I have gotten as far as using this query

```
SELECT
    1 AS Count,
    struct ( REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA,'$.audiences_joined_at'), r'"([^"]+)":') as Audience_Name,
    CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA,'$.audiences_joined_at'), r':[ ]*([^,}\]]+)') AS INT64) as Audience_joinDate) as AudienceGrowth,
  FROM
    `ti-ga-dev-master-view-no-bots.tealium_pub_sub_poc.pub_sub_subscription_direct_partitioned`
  WHERE
    DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = (CURRENT_DATE()-1)
```

and this gives me an output that looks like this

[image: BigQuery output]

I'm not quite sure how to proceed, or if I'm even on the right track here.

Answer (score 0):

Because the key is the id of the user and is more like a value and is not known to you, you need to use regex. BigQuery JSON is not able to handle this.
The `struct` in your code does not make sense.

The following code is splitted in several CTE parts:

```
with table1 as (Select ...)
```

The function `timestamp_millis(1685424724368)` converts integer values the timestamp.

```sql
With tbl as 
(
Select 1 as id, JSON """
{
"properties": {
        "visitor_id": "011238234d13456005675fghce678fdh3f00cb00d00b40__"
    },   
 "audiences_joined_at": {
        "ti_main_522": 1685423385711,
        "ti_main_224": 1685424724368,
        "ti_main_314": 1685017676965,
        "ti_main_523": 1685424724369,
        "ti_main_129": 1685017676965,
        "ti_main_239": 1685017676965,
        "ti_main_437": 1685424724369,
        "ti_main_506": 1685424724369,
        "ti_main_393": 1685424724369,
        "ti_main_164": 1685017676965,
        "ti_main_197": 1685158341719,
        "ti_main_296": 1685158341719,
        "ti_main_340": 1685158341719,
        "ti_main_263": 1685017676965,
        "ti_main_174": 1685424831154,
        "ti_main_399": 1685424724369,
        "ti_main_354": 1685017676965,
        "ti_main_457": 1685426669254
    }
}
""" as data
),
parsed_tbl as (
SELECT
    id,
    JSON_VALUE(data, "$.properties.visitor_id") as visitor_id,
    struct(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(to_json_string(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA,'$.audiences_joined_at')), r'"([^"]+)":') as Audience_Name,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(to_json_string(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA,'$.audiences_joined_at')), r':[ ]*([^,}\]]+)') as Audience_joinDate)
    as AudienceGrowth
 from tbl
),
unnest_tbl as (
Select * except(AudienceGrowth),
timestamp_millis(cast(Audience_joinDate_ as int64)) as join_date
  from parsed_tbl, 
  unnest(AudienceGrowth.Audience_Name) Audience_Name_ with offset,
  unnest(AudienceGrowth.Audience_joinDate) Audience_joinDate_ with offset offset2
  where offset=offset2
)
select
visitor_id, 
join_date,
count(Audience_Name_) as users
from unnest_tbl
group by 1,2
```